# Problème with async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py, python-asyncio

i have a function that check every 30 second if a streamer is on live. it work with a while true whith if inside and a time.sleep(30) at the end of the while.

```py
stream = request_twitch_stream("can't show", "can't show", "can't show") #return all the information about a live (view, title, streamer_ame etc)

    embed_on=discord.Embed(title=stream[1],  url="https://twitch.tv/" + stream[0], description=stream[0] + " is on ive !", color=0x30e8d3)
    embed_on.set_author(name=stream[0])
    embed_on.add_field(name="Game", value=stream[2], inline=False)
    embed_on.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/914275966883364895/1034034979119841341/pdp_discord.png")
    embed_on.set_footer(text="Made by Xalri")
  

    embed_off=discord.Embed(title="Offline", description=stream[0] + "is not on live", color=0x30e8d3)
    embed_off.set_author(name=stream[0], url="https://twitch.tv/" + stream[0])
    embed_off.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/914275966883364895/1034034979119841341/pdp_discord.png")
    embed_off.set_footer(text="Made by Xalri")

    def check_stream():
      
      prev = True
        
      while True:

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
               
        if request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", "can't show"): #return True or False if the streamer is on live or not 
    
          if request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", "can't show") == prev:
            pass
          else:

            stream_channel.purge()
            
            prev = request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", "can't show")
    
            stream_channel.send(embed=embed_on)

        else : 
           
          if request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", "can't show") == prev :
            pass
          else:
    
            prev = request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", "can't show")
    
            await stream_channel.purge()
            
            print("else else")

            await stream_channel.send(embed=embed_off)
            
            loop.run_forever()
        
        #sleep(30)

        

        sleep(30)

    
    t = Thread(target=check_stream)
    t.start()
```

I need to remove the await on the two "stream_channel.purge()" and on the two "stream_channel.send(embed=embed_on/off)" because i run my fnction check_stream in a thread so the function can't be async

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize your function `check_stream` as follows.  All of your code before and after this function can remain the same.

```
def check_stream():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    prev = True
    while True:
        if request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", "can't show"):
            #return True or False if the streamer is on live or not
            if request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", 
                                          "can't show") == prev:
                pass
            else:
                stream_channel.purge()
                prev = request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", 
                                                  "can't show")
                stream_channel.send(embed=embed_on)
        else:
            if request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", 
                                          "can't show") == prev:
                pass
            else:
                prev = request_twitch_stream_bool("can't show", "can't show", 
                                                  "can't show")
                loop.run_until_complete(stream_channel.purge())
                print("else else")
                loop.run_until_complete(stream_channel.send(embed=embed_off))
        sleep(30)
```

The changes I made, besides some formatting, are:

- I created and set an event loop at the top of the function.  This must be done any time you want to run async functions outside the main thread.  You should typically do this only once per thread, so it should be outside the while loop.
- Replaced your await expressions with calls to `loop.run_until_complete()`.  This method will run the async function and wait for it to complete, which is what you are trying to do at that point (I think).
- Removed the call to loop.run_forever, which was not the correct approach for this problem.

You said you wanted to remove the `await` but you cannot execute a coroutine without having an event loop running in the thread.  Sometimes you can use the `loop.run_until_complete` method to execute async code without use of the await keyword.  But the event loop will stop running as soon as the coroutine finishes.  In this case, this works because the program logic is simple enough.

You said that you cannot have an async function in a secondary thread.  That's not correct.  In a secondary thread you must explicitly initialize the event loop.  But once you do that, asyncio works just the same way in a secondary thread as it does in the main thread.